# Does sequence converge in probability?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3,...$ be a sequence of nonnegative random variables such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} E[X_n]=0$.

I want to know if the sequence $Y_n=1-e^{-X_n}$ converges in probability and if so, what is the limit.

My thought is to approach this problem using the Markov inequality:

$$P[X>\epsilon]\leq\frac{E[X]}{\epsilon}$$

Then, by plugging in $Y_n$, I get,

$$P[Y_n>\epsilon]\leq\frac{E[1-e^{-X_n}]}{\epsilon}$$

and since  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} E[X_n]=0$, then $E[1-e^{-X_n}]$ must also go to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.  Therefore, $Y_n$ converges in probability to $0$.

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: What is the meaning of $X_n$?

Comment: Of course, you might be asked to include a proof of the step that $E(X_n)\to0$ implies $E(1-e^{-X_n})\to0$. Can you do that?

Comment: @callculus There is no specific meaning other than what is stated.  X_i are a sequence of rvs and the limit of that sequence has a mean of zer0.

Comment: @Did I believe the way to show is to use linearity ff expectation to break it into $E[1] - E[e^{-X_n}]$ and because $E[X_n]$ goes to zero, $E[e^{-X_n}]$ must go to one.  Is that correct? I tried to break down $E[e^{-X_n}]$  more using LOTUS but didn't get anywhere (perhaps I made a mistake).

Comment: @Avedis But I don´t know what is meant by "sequence" in this context. Maybe $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$?

Comment: @callculus It doesnt mean what you implied.  It could, but the problem is specifically not commenting.  You are given the facts that you have a sequence, the rv's are non-negative, and the expectation of the limit is 0.

Comment: @Avedis OK, I´ve understood. Thanks for clarification and I hope Did can give you some further hints.

Comment: You are again **asserting** that $E(X_n)\to0$ implies $E(e^{-X_n})\to1$, not proving it. Can you **prove** this?

Comment: No. I tried using LOTUS to prove but it didn't work. Can you give a hint?

Comment: @Did It looks like Jensen's inequality might work.  Is this what you meant by convexity? 1-e^-E[x] <= E[1-e^-x].

Comment: @Did Actually, I dont think Jensen's inequality will work, 1-e^-x is not convex but concave.

Comment: True, sorry for the brain fart...

Comment: @Did so i think the only answer that works is the one given by Shashi.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well known that
$$0\leq 1-e^{-x}\leq x$$
for all $x\geq 0$ (this fact can be easily proven using Mean Value Theorem for instance). In the particular problem you are considering the inequality translates to
$$0\leq Y_n \leq X_n$$
That gives  the result
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb E|Y_n|=0$$
Hence $Y_n$ converges to $0$ in $L^1$ so it converges in probability as well (by Markov's inequality). You indeed said the result; here is a way to prove it.